# Core Identity Razor Pages or directly use User/Role/SignIn Managers

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have been studying **Core Identity** to implement security in a new **ASP.NET Core 5** project and I see that I can use the **Identity Razor Pages** already implemented. However, this would result in 2 development approaches in the same project: **MVC** and **Razor Pages**.

Also, I have the choice to directly use **SignInManager**, **UserManager** and **RoleManager** classes to implement the desired functionality following the MVC pattern. In this way, all of my project would be a one-pattern-project.

Is there a reason to avoid mixing **MVC** and **Razor Pages** in a project?
Is it a good/bad practice?
From a pro perspective, how does mixing **MVC** and **Razor** approaches look?

Respectfully,

Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Opinion-based questions are normally off-topic here. But, anyway, it sounds normal & perfectly fine. The Razor pages simply serve as the **V**iew of **MVC** where ever you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

I have MVC project with razor pages for Identity. It doesn't look messy. However now I have Razor pages project and I do my best to avoid MVC in there to keep tidy. I would say try and keep it clean, but if the best way is to make a reasonable mess then go with it.

You could move your razor pages into the View folder for cleaner structure. I know scaffolding puts the in Area folder which in my opinion was kinda off.